# Return property directly when class is called (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, oop

I have a class called foo with only property `M`,

```
classdef foo     
    properties
        M
    end

    methods
        function obj = foo(arg1)
            M=arg1;
        end
    end
end
```

and I create the object:

```
F=foo(1)
```

In C++ it is possible, that when I call `F`, that I directly get the value of one chosen variable. In my case I would like to get `F.M` when I just write `F`. For example this would allow to write

```
size(F)
```

instead of writing

```
size(F.M)
```

or defining a method `size` for my class. Is there a way in MATLAB to achieve this?

---

Edit: In other words, whenever I write `F`, I want that MATLAB reads it as `F.M`.

---

Edit: I will clarify what I want to acchieve.
My class represents a matrix whose values are multivariate infinite sequences with compact support. Thus I have to do a lot of bookkeeping not to mix up all the indices. Things I want to do with my matrix:

- Matrix multiplication.
- Convolution.
- Upsampling, downsampling.
- Everything else which is possible in a vector/matrix space.

I thought this is easier to acchieve when I encapsulate all the meta-data (this are the indices of the 0^th entries of the sequence) together with the data. 
Because my class is actually a matrix, most operations work on that class in the same way as on ordinary matrices. Therefore I do not want to code it all over again (Because of code-maintenance, less bugs, code-readability).

In C++ I could do it that way. It seems, my approach to that problem is the wrong one in MATLAB.

Comment: MATLAB's OOP capabilities are not exactly known for being bleeding-edge. I don't think this is possible under the restrictions you mentioned.

Comment: Is the variable `M` read only once its been created? or do you want it to be able to update it after its been created?

Comment: So it now sounds as if you want to create a new data type which will behave exactly like a matrix but has a different implementation under the hood, a bit like MATLAB's sparse matrices. If this is at all possible, I think your best chance of getting advice is going to be from a serious expert via the Mathworks site. Meanwhile, [here's how sparse matrices are implemented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/otherdocs/simax.pdf).

Comment: The line `F=foo(1)` created a variable of the class `foo`. If you want `size` to return the size of the main attribute you maybe have to overload this function. So append a function called `size` to your object definition and return the size of the main matrix... I don't know if this works in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to overload the function `size` as I mentioned in my comment.

```
classdef foo
    properties
        M
    end

    methods
        function obj = foo(arg)
            obj.M = arg;
        end

        function varargout = size(obj, varargin)
            if nargin == 1
                varargout = size(obj.M);
            elseif nargin == 2 && nargout == 1
                varargout = size(obj.M, varargin{1})
            else
                error('Wrong number of input or output arguments.')
            end
        end
        function ret = mtimes(varargin)
            try
                ret = varargin{1}.M * varargin{2};
            catch
                ret = varargin{1} * varargin{2}.M;
            end
        end
    end

end
```

Console Output:

```
>> F=foo(0:3);
>> size(F)

ans =

     1     4

>> size(F, 2)

ans =

     4

>> F*(4:7).'

ans =

    38

>> (4:7).'*F

ans =

     0     4     8    12
     0     5    10    15
     0     6    12    18
     0     7    14    21
```

I could continue but preparing the console output for StackOverflow is horrible...

Comment: I don't know why the other answers disappeard, together with my comments. There I wrote, that this is not what I want to do. Particularly, because then I still can't write: size(F,2) e.g. .

Comment: I know I could write this, but as I already wrote in my question: That is exactly that what I want to aviod, since it is useless code-repetition which only makes problem.

Comment: But this is the only way to implement it as far as I know.